# 'function' object has no attribute 'user' error in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I get this error when I use:
`@login_required('/login_backend/')` in my views.

I am using Django 1.5. My user model is:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    #id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    #identifier = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=90, unique=True, db_index=True)
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    update_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    #password = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    external = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    deleted = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    purged = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    form_values_id = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    disk_usage = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=16, decimal_places=0, blank=True)
    #last_login = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'galaxy_user'
```

How to solve this?

**Edit:** My view code:

```
def login_backend(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/overview/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('login_backend.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required('/login_backend/')
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')

@login_required('/login_backend/')
def show_files(request):
    try:
        log_id = request.user.id
        username = request.user.username
        b = File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id, flag='F', flag_r='S')  # Get the user id from session .delete() to use delete
        total_files = File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id, flag='F').count()
        total_size = File.objects.filter(users_id=log_id, flag='F').aggregate(Sum('size_overview'))
        total_size = total_size['size_overview__sum']
        total_size = size(total_size, system=alternative)
        return render_to_response('overview.html', {'overview_files': b, 'total_files':total_files, 'total_size':total_size, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    except TypeError:
        return render_to_response('overview.html', {'overview_files': b, 'total_files':total_files, 'total_size':total_size, 'username': username}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  103.                     resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  321.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  223.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  29.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/zurelsoft/workspace/genalytics/fileupload/backend.py" in <module>
  37. @login_required('/login_backend/')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  24.             if test_func(request.user):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /login_backend/
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Comment: Please post your view code (along with the login_required decorator), that's most likely where the error happens; can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Thinking about it, the traceback would help as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be incorrect use of the `login_required` decorator. According to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator), the decorator takes two optional keyword arguments, `redirect_field_name` and `login_url`. Emphasis on the expression *keyword arguments*.

I'm not entirely sure what it is you want to achieve with the `'/login_backend/'` argument to the decorator, but if you pass it directly as the first argument, the decorator takes this as the function you want to decorate and bad stuff happens.

To fix (and this is only a guess on my part), try

```
@login_required(login_url='/login_backend/')
```

Comment: I had faced a similar situation. This has really helped me. I thought it had something to do with my AbstractUser and I almost started rewriting some of my model code.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'))
def startPage(request):
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could try is to add the following line to the bottom of your settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL='/login_backend/'
```

This should allow you to use the decorator without having to specify the login argument like the example below.

```
@login_required
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login_backend/')
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with a custom decorator. They behave differently if you try to pass an argument vs if you don't. If you pass an argument, you need to wrap the regular decorator function you would be returning with another function that will accept these argument.

```
def my_decorator(condition, trueDec, falseDec):
    def original_decorator(view_func):
        @functools.wraps(view_func)
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            ....
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return original_decorator
```